# Using variables in Skype URís

Tags: javascript, variables, uri, skype

I'm trying to use Skype Uri's in a windows application. In my application I have one button that starts a chat with a Skype user, it Works just great but I wish to know if there's some way to send a variable as a parameter instead of sending the Skype user explicitly, this is the code that works fine:

```
Skype.ui({
      "name": "dropdown",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_daniel43611_1",
      "participants": “marco.antonio.aleman”,
      "imageSize": 10
    });
```

In the line “participants” I would like to send a variable (like reading from a field of a table in a database, or assigning a value to it) with the name of the Skype user I wish to chat. Something like this:

```
Var skypeuser = “marco.antonio.aleman” (could it be a field from a table?)
Skype.ui({
      "name": "dropdown",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_daniel43611_1",
      "participants": skypeuser,
      "imageSize": 10
    });
```

Is it possible to do something like that?
What would be the syntax?

I have search in forums and other sites but nobody seem to have the same question, even asked in Skype developer support but they answer was very strange, they told me they are no programming experts, that i might want to search help somewhere else!!!! sounds weird coming from a program manager of a developer team!

Comment: I re-tagged as I think you mean *JavaScript* which is completely different from *Java*.

Comment: @AlexK. good job. but remove the java tag next time

Comment: Thanks Alex and Phillip

Comment: how did you import the Skype javascript in the first place? I can't do it using react js